# How to use Python faker for dependent columns

Tags: python, pandas, faker

**Scenario**
If column1 = ‘Value’ then column2 = ‘AAA’

How can we use faker to generate mock data for these dependent columns. Need to consider both positive and negative data.

Comment: Need more detail to understand the context

Comment: I would need to generate mock data where the columns are dependent on each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Faker` database like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from faker.providers import date_time

df = (pd.DataFrame(date_time.Provider.countries, columns=['name', 'alpha-2-code'])
        .rename(columns={'name': 'country', 'alpha-2-code': 'country_code'})
        .sample(n=1000, replace=True, ignore_index=True, random_state=2022))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                              country country_code
0                              Rwanda           RW
1                             Grenada           GD
2                                Oman           OM
3                             Moldova           MD
4    Saint Vincent and the Grenadines           VC
..                                ...          ...
995                           Iceland           IS
996                        Seychelles           SC
997                            Israel           IL
998                 Equatorial Guinea           GQ
999               Republic of Ireland           IE

[1000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Or use `pycountry`.

Comment: Updated the question. Need solution to be generic. It’s not specific to country code.